# How to override the parser in Caliburn Micro?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I would like to add keyboard shortcut in an desktop app using `Caliburn Micro` in the way described in [here](http://www.siimviikman.com/2012/06/28/caliburn-adding-keyboard-shortcuts/comment-page-1/). But I totally have no idea how to override the `parser`. Should I attach the class `ShortcutParser` in the class `Parse` in Caliburn Micro, and place the following code somewhere?

```
var currentParser = Parser.CreateTrigger;
Parser.CreateTrigger = (target, triggerText) => ShortcutParser.CanParse(triggerText)
                                                ? ShortcutParser.CreateTrigger(triggerText)
                                                : currentParser(target, triggerText);
```

I posted a comment to seek help from the author, but no response. Please help me out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was something that a couple of guys came up with on the older forums.

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=caliburnmicro discussions look for #id 243905 or search for `KeyTrigger convention` on the discussions tab..

as the comment suggests post is indeed dead but the code and archive still carry the results..

Comment: Link is dead, and this answer became useless.

Comment: thanks for working a little harder to find it with a simple open your eyes.  And now the answer is good again thanks for the -2 points..

Comment: Don't take this personally, please. But because of this particular situation You should put code in your answer and put link where You found it, instead of just putting link which can (has) become dead.